# jQuery dialog not appearing fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's something wrong with my jQuery popup dialog. Only the image and the "close" hyperlink is appearing. I was thinking I would get a nice-looking UI as per this example: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Here is what is happening:

[image: oh so empty...]

Here is my code:

```
theDiv.append('<div id="editDialog"></div>');
    $("#editDialog").dialog({
    height: 350,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen:true,
        title:'Hello World',
        zIndex: 10000,
        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
    });
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: are you sure you linked the css file and the images are placed where the css file thinks they are?

Comment: oh jesus, do I need to include a css script from the jquery site?

Comment: ofc, how do you expect to have the dialog styled without css?

Comment: I thought maybe the jquery.js did it dynamically or something... Arg, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments i understand that you should read this guide: [jQuery UI - Getting Started](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 1):

I thing you did not added jquery-custom css and jquery-custom js files, for explore it please take a look here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal, and you can download demo and documentation from here http://jqueryui.com/download.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.